# Модератор, который смог 100к!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Поздравляем [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) с достижением 100к репутации. Удачи в покорении новых высот. И помните, что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Qwertiy, мои поздравления. Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо за поздравления, но есть подозрения, что они немного преждевременны. Меня смущает значительное количество плюсов по старым сообщениям с утра - полагаю, завтра снова станет меньше 100К. Но всё равно я где-то близко :)

Comment: Я уж тоже хотел написать этот вопрос, но чуть-чуть не успел.

Comment: @Qwertiy Поздравляю!!! ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Чтобы вопрос был формально вопросом :) - когда планируется 200K? :)

Comment: @Harry когда планируете 150k? :)

Comment: @Danis Когда достаточное количество интересных вопросов совпадет с достаточным количеством свободного времени и не менее достаточным количеством тех, кто положительно ценит ответы :)

Comment: @Harry по моим расчётом вы наберёте 150k репутации через 20 дней

Comment: @Danis Так, 2-3 ноября. Ставлю напоминалку, проверим :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, поздравляю! И дальше так держать!

Comment: @Qwertiy Поздравляю с деревянной медалью (так в спорте называют 4 место)         На самом деле я очень рад за тебя, присоединяюсь к поздравлениям коллег! Кстати традиционный вопрос, как ко всем стотысячникам, какой медалью, достижением в метке, ты больше всего рад (гордишься)

Comment: @Harry кажется я немного ошибся с датой

Comment: @Danis Бывали интересные вопросы :) Но я могу остановиться и не отвечать несколько дней?...

Comment: @Danis Конечно, нет. Особенно против плодить аккаунты...

Answer (score 16):

От лица сообщества поздравляю вас с достижением порога в 100 000 баллов репутации!  Огромное спасибо за ваш вклад в развитие русскоязычной базы знаний! С нетерпением ждем ваших новых вопросов и ответов =)

Comment: @Qwertiy Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям. Успехов, быстрого роста, и просто приятного времяприпровождения )

Answer (score 10):

Поздравляю @Qwertiy/, но так же о**громная благодарность всем** тем, кто отвечает на вопросы участников. Добра мира и здоровья всем, кто читает это.

[image: Люди которые отвечают на вопросы в форуме]

Answer (score 6):

Я конечно поздравить от лица сообщества права не имею, но зато могу поздравить от своего лица ;) Так что, собственно говоря:

## Поздравляю!

И желаю будущих успехов как в модерировании, так и как обычному участнику. Не зря ведь говорится, что модератором должен быть — лидер сообщетва. Желаю так же в скорости достигнуть 200k ;)

Answer (score 3):

Поздравляю! Ждём 200k репутации!